# why is my ByteArrayInputStream empty after creating it from any string?

Tags: java, groovy, inputstream

Basically I'm using (in `groovy`) the following construction:

```
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream("one two three four".getBytes());
```

but then when I print its content:

```
println(in.text)
```

I see empty line. Why so? and how can I save those bytes in my InputStream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original code gives me a compilation error in Groovy Console:

```
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream("one two three four".getBytes());
println(in.text)

1 compilation error:

expecting EOF, found 'in' at line: 1, column: 13
```

`in` is a reserved word in Groovy. Changing it to `inn` all work well:

```
InputStream inn = new ByteArrayInputStream("one two three four".getBytes())
println(inn.text)
```

With this output:

```
one two three four
```

Answer (score 0):

The bytes are in the `InputStream`, your just printing it wrong. Try converting the `InputStream` to a `String` with a `Scanner`, and then printing it.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(in).useDelimeter("\\Z");
while (s.hasNext()) {
    System.out.print(s.next());
}
```